# CUH comsumption of a deployed SPSS modeler flow

Tags: watson-studio, spss-modeler

Recently, I deployed a SPSS flow with Watson Studio and the Machine Learning service to use with a Web Service. After few days, trying to use de deployed model using Soap UI, it displays "this deployment cannot be processed because it exceeds the allocated capacity unit hours(CUH)". But, we didn't useit to predict more than 30 times. In the monitoring panel, the CUH hours are practically unused (0,4 used of 50). I couldn't understand this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In my case they said that was related to the number of capacity unit hour (CUH) consumed. I send an e-mail to IBM to check about it. And it happens bcs I had unfortunately used all the capacity of my signature, and I could only conclude if I made an update of my account plan on the IBM platform OR create another account.
I hope to have helped ;)